# extracting numbers and characters from a string, which doesn't follow a specific format? (postfix calculator)

Tags: c++, string, extract, postfix-notation

I'm having trouble separating numbers and characters from my input string. The purpose of my program is to add,subtract,multiply and divide in **postfix**
so i cant predict the input form as it can be anything from
**2 2 3 + * (answer being 10)** to **2 2 + 3 * (answer being 12)**. So i cant use sscanf to extract the numbers and the operator character without having a specific format to the input string. What should i do here?

Comment: Is this homework? Your comment that you're "required to use gets, then convert" seems to indicate so.

Comment: yes it is, I'm stuck at this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to process postfix you're going to want to implement a stack, so you should push each number onto a stack as you get it, each operator pops two off the stack and pushes the result back.

Comment: I'm using a stack, but for the input im required to use gets,and then convert and push the numbers onto the stack...

Comment: why don't use isalpha() to detect whether it was numbers or operator

Comment: Required to use gets? Tell your teacher that this function is broken by design. The manual page says -- Never use gets().  Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it  is  extremely dangerous to use.  It has been used to break computer security.  Use fgets() instead.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `scanf("%s")` which will return characters up to the next whitespace. Or you could use `getc` to get characters one at a time.

## edit:

I see from comments that you are using gets to read in a whole line, in that case, you might be better off using [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) in a loop to break the line up into tokens and then look at the first character of each token to decide what to do with it.

```
char line[MAX_LINE];
// read in the line 

char * pTok = strtok(line, " \t");
while (pTok)
{
    char ch = pTok[0];
    if (isdigit(ch))
       //handle number

    if (ch == '+')
       //handle addition operator
   
    ...
    pTok = strtok(NULL, " \t");
}
```

Comment: He's using C++, so the equivalents would be std::cin >> val (skips whitespace and tries to read a number) and std::cin.clear(); std::cin.get(ch) after reading a number fails.

Comment: @Tronic: He was the one that mentioned sscanf.  C++ code isn't _required_ to use std::.

Comment: i could use scanf but the amount of numbers being calculated is variable

Comment: You need to loop and only read one value at a time, at most (none if the next token is something non-numeric).

Comment: im trying that now, but what if the integer is more than one character?

Comment: hmmm is there a way i can just extract all the numbers and store them in variables?. I can test for the operators in  a loop and act accordingly.

Comment: I'm at a loss can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Boost.Spirit Qi, which is a really nice parser library. The first example is a calculator...

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/introduction.html

A standard-library only solution:

```
// Get a line of user input (simplifies I/O)
std::string line;
if (!std::getline(std::cin, line)) throw std::runtime_error("Unable to read line");
// Process the line as an input string stream
std::istringstream iss(line);
while (true) {
    unsigned int val;
    if (iss >> val) {
        // TODO: Handle a numeric value (in val)
        continue;
    }
    iss.clear(); // Clear the error state
    char ch;
    if (!iss.get(ch)) break; // Break the loop if there is no more input
    // TODO: Handle a character (in ch)
}
```

Comment: Updated with stdlib solution.

Comment: for homework it is probably better to stick to the basics in stead of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do this by grabbing a whole line, then have a function taking a string, an offset and a return struct. The return struct contains the start and end offset of the token, the token type (operator, argument) and possibly some other things.

Alternatively, split it into two functions, one that checks for a number and one that checks for an operator.